# How to specify which value is returned for a foreign field when serialising data in a view in Django

Tags: django, serialization

I have a model containing a ForeignKey to another model. I am attempting to serialize this model and want to control what field is returned for the foreignkey field. See below:

models.py

```
class Surveyor(models.Model):
    num = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Anblsrecord(models.Model):
    ...
    sur_num = models.ForeignKey(Surveyor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def anbls_points(request):
    points_as_geojson = serialize('geojson', Anblsrecord.objects.all()[:5], fields=(... 'sur_num'))
    return JsonResponse(json.loads(points_as_geojson))
```

When I view this I get:
... "sur_num": 1 ...
where the "1" is "num" from Surveyor class. I want to return "name".

I looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/ which talks about multi-table inheritance, but I can't find anything for a related table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The built-in serialization is not very flexible; I would suggest looking into Django Rest Framework serializers where you could use a `CharField` with the [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument set to `sur_num.name`.

Answer (score 1):

Django Rest Framework serializers with [django-rest-framework-gis](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis#django-rest-framework-gis) worked:

## serializers.py

```
from anblsrecords import models
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoFeatureModelSerializer
class AnblsrecordSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    sur_name = serializers.CharField(source='sur_num.name')
    class Meta:        
        model = models.Anblsrecord
        geo_field = "geom"
        fields = (
            ...
            'sur_name',        
        )
```

## views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
class ListAnbls_points(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Anblsrecord.objects.all()[:5]
    serializer_class = serializers.AnblsrecordSerializer
```

This returns:
"properties": {
                ...,
                "sur_name": "Name of Surveyor",...}, and includes the geometry feature.